# workbook.open runtime error 424

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to load a few workbooks with Workbook.Open and in every case, I get "Runtime Error '424': Object Required"

The offending code is:

```
Const path As String = "\\networkpath\data\"

Sub LoadReports()
Dim date_ext As String
date_ext = "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"

Workbook.Open path & "ReportX" & date_ext   ' This is where the runtime error occurs
End Sub
```

The path and filename should resolve to "\\networkpath\data\ReportX_2017-07-14.xlsm" if the date is 7/14/2017.

When I comment out the Workbook.Open and manually open the files prior to running the full macro, everything works fine.  Even more perplexing is that in other macros in other workbooks, the exact same code works fine.  When I searched Runtime Error 424 and/or Workbook.Open, I could not find anything that I did not already know, like that the filename parameter is looking for a string that includes the path.  I am not sure what is wrong here.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `Workbooks.Open`, not `Workbook.Open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start by putting a test workbook on server. name it abc123.xlsm

then try this

```
Sub testLoadReport()
    Workbooks.Open "\\networkpath\data\abc123.xlsm"
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It just shows that fixing the typo will make it work, but you don't mention that the typo is the issue.  And questions caused by typos are off-topic on SO ("This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.") so there's no real need to post an answer - just point out the typo in a comment.

Comment: i have no idea if it is the typo that caused the problem. this code snippet  should confirm whether any file is actually accessible in that directory, before trying to figure what the actual problem might be.  i am also trying to advise @Turkish on what to do in similar situations. (ie. remove as much code as possible from the suspect pool)

Comment: With an error saying `"Runtime Error '424': Object Required"` and no object on that line due to the typo, I can guarantee you that it **is** the typo that is generating the error.

Comment: Thanks, it was the typo and I feel like an idiot for missing it... I literally spent 2 hours bashing my head against the wall... for a typo!

Comment: @Turkish I recommend you delete the question - errors caused by typos are off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: lol! @Turkish, bashing your head is a normal part of writing code